My list of maps updates only after hot reload (using GetX)
That's my controller:
class MyAppliesController extends GetxController {  
 RxMap<int, List<NewDocumentsRequest>> applicantDocuments =
      <int, List<NewDocumentsRequest>>{}.obs;

void addDocumentToList(
      int applicantId, NewDocumentsRequest document, VisaModel visaModel) {
    if (!applicantDocuments.containsKey(applicantId)) {
      applicantDocuments[applicantId] = [];
    }
    bool documentExists = applicantDocuments[applicantId]!.any(
        (existingDocument) =>
            existingDocument.documentType == document.documentType);
    if (!documentExists) {
      if (applicantDocuments[applicantId]!.length <
          visaModel.visaApplicants![applicantId].visaDocuments!.length) {
        applicantDocuments[applicantId]!.add(document);
      } else {
        print('Applicant already has 3 documents');
      }
    } else {
      errorSnackBar('alreadyDownload');
      errorSnackBar('alreadyDownload');
    }

}
}

In my modal bottom sheet I add document to my List:
 CustomButton(
              text: 'add'.tr,
              onTap: () async {
                final base64 =
                    await ImageService.imageToBase64(ctrl.downloadedFile.value);
                ctrl.addDocumentToList(
                    index,
                    NewDocumentsRequest(
                      visaApplicantId: data.visaApplicants?[index].id ?? 0,
                      documentType: documentType,
                      document: base64,
                      documentTypeName: getDocumentTypeName(documentType),
                    ),
                    data);
                Get.back();
                print(
                  NewDocumentsRequest(
                    visaApplicantId: data.visaApplicants?[index].id ?? 0,
                    documentType: documentType,
                    document: base64,
                    documentTypeName: getDocumentTypeName(documentType),
                  ),
                );
                ctrl.downloadedFile.value = File('');
              }), 

And in my another screen I show it :
ctrl.applicantDocuments[i] == null
                          ? const SizedBox()
                          : Obx(() {
                              return ListView.builder(
                                  physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  itemCount: ctrl.applicantDocuments[i]?.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                                    final documents =
                                        // ignore: invalid_use_of_protected_member
                                        ctrl.applicantDocuments.value[i];

                                    // print(ctrl.applicantDocuments[i]);
                                    // print(
                                    //   ctrl.applicantDocuments.length,
                                    // );
                                    return DownloadDocTile(
                                      title: documents?[index]
                                              .documentTypeName
                                              .toString() ??
                                          '',
                                      trailing: Icon(
                                        FontAwesomeIcons.circleQuestion,
                                        color: AppColors.neutral700,
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  });
                            })

After I added new item to my list it updates only when I press hot reload. Obx is not updating it automatically. What is the problem here? And when I add 'value' after my list like :                                        ctrl.applicantDocuments.value[i];
It shows
The member 'value' can only be used within instance members of subclasses of 'package:get/get_rx/src/rx_types/rx_iterables/rx_map.dart'.

I tried so many things, but nothing works, maybe I initialized it wrong. Help please

Adding a document doesn't actually change the map, since it still will have the same collection of lists. You are adding to the list inside that map. This wouldn't notify the Obx. To make it update you should call refresh() right after adding the document. so like
applicantDocuments[applicantId]!.add(document);
applicantDocuments.refresh();

Alternatively you make it a map of RxList instead List. I believe that should also work, but just using normal lists and calling refresh should be fine.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work :(
